# Why doesn't my code for printing a simple Linked List work?

Tags: c++, data-structures, structure

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct NODE node;

typedef struct NODE {
  int marks;
  char name[100];
  node *next;
} node;

node *getinput() {
  node *n;
  n = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (n) {
    cin >> n->marks; // STATEMENT 1
    gets_s(n->name);
    n->next = NULL;
  }
  return n;
}

node *populateList(node *list) {
  node *temp;
  node *newptr = getinput();
  if (list == NULL) {
    list = newptr;
    return list;
  }

  temp = list;
  while (temp->next) {
    temp = temp->next;

    //(COMMENT 1)temp->next = newptr;
  }

  temp->next = newptr;
  return list;
}

void printlist(node *list) {
  node *p = list;

  // temp = list;
  while (p->next) {
    cout << p->marks << endl; // STATEMENT 2

    //(COMMENT 3) cout << list->marks << endl;

    puts(p->name);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

void main() {
  int x = 1;
  node *n = NULL;

  for (; x <= 6; x++)
    n = populateList(n);

  printlist(n);
}
```

So, there are some issues that I'm facing :

1. I'm not able to take the desired marks and names of 6 members, but rather I can take the names of the 6 members, but not their marks. (The same output shows if I remove STATEMENT 1 AND/OR STATEMENT 2).
2. I presume the marks of the members are taken as the junk value of the pointer **node * list** of the linked list,since it seems to be the same for all the members.

So how do I do about resolving the issues in my program? I understand that this problem may seem too trivial to many, and I can easily look up in the internet for a Linked List program, but I'm determined to make this work. I would like to know further issues/optimizations in the code, so that I can correct myself.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: [Off Topic] `node * n; n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` should be `node* n = new node;` at least

Comment: As an aside, why are you using so many C idioms in your C++ code? `typedef struct`, `malloc()`, `puts()`, while all legal C++, have all been replaced by more interesting paradigms.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why you ensure `p->next` is valid before printing `p`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link. I think this would help me a long way.

Comment: @Robᵩ This is because it was actually intended to be a C program. But then again it refers to ignorance on my part regarding the idioms, for I did code in c++.

Comment: @user4581301 This is a mistake on my part. As it is, it obviously won't print the last member of the list. Or do you want something else?

Comment: @user73157 no, you got the gist of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing C++ with C code, 
some small fixes for you.
use `std::string name` instead of `char name[100]`
use `n = new node()`

and lastly for you "bug" you should switch `gets_s(n->name);` to `cin >> (n->name);`
this will work and fill the correct value for the marks and name.
i am pretty sure the problem come from mixing input from stdin using C++ functions `cin` and C function `gets_s` where it looks like gets_s take the separator of the value after the first `cin` is called.

also don't forget to delete the allocated nodes.

Comment: Just a remark: `cin >> n->name` will not be able to read in a name like `"john doe"`, because it would stop after `john`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code; the one leading to incorrectly dealing with input is that you mix `cin` with `gets_s`, which often does not work as intended; BTW: `gets_s` or `gets` are "old fashioned C-style and deprecated (or even removed) in newer standards. Use, for example, `std::getline` as replacement.

It's actually a little bit tricky to mix reading in integral values and strings with white spaces. For example, if an input is `10 john doe`, then `cin >> marks` would read in `10`, but will leave the blank in the input buffer; you will have to skip white spaces, e.g. by `cin >> ws`; otherwise, your string input would either terminate immediately or - if used `getline`- contain a blank at the beginning.  Then, if you write `string name; cin >> name`, then only `john` would be read, because string input stops with the first white space. So I'd suggest to read the name until the end of line using `getline`, such that you really get `john doe` as name.

Further, please take into account that input may fail (e.g. end of file or invalid format), such that `getinput` might have to return an invalid node (which should be represented by `nullptr`).

A lot of things, so I rewrote your code a little bit to take above mentioned things into account. Hope it helps; have fun with coding!

```
struct node {
    int marks;
    string name;
    node *next;
};

node *getinput() {
    int marks;
    string name;
    if (! (cin >> marks >> std::ws)) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (! getline(cin, name, '\n')) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return new node { marks, name, nullptr };
}

node *addToList(node *list, node* newNode) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return newNode;
    }
    if (newNode == nullptr) {
        return list;
    }

    node* temp = list;
    while (temp->next) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newNode;
    return list;
}

void printlist(node *list) {
    node *p = list;
    while (p) {
        cout << p->marks << " " << p->name << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    node *n = NULL;
    node *list = NULL;

    while (x <= 3 && (n = getinput()) != nullptr) {
        list = addToList(list, n);
        x++;
    }

    printlist(list);
}
```